# Is it legal for a public US university to advise its employees to purchase from businesses owned by people of color?

Tags: united-states, discrimination

A public US university I'm familiar with is promoting an anti-racism initiative. As part of this initiative, a web article posted on the university's diversity web portal (which was advertised in an email newsletter to the university community) contains a list of suggested actions that employees and departments can take to advance the cause of anti-racism. One of the actions on the list is to support businesses owned by people of color. The recommendation is accompanied by links to various lists of black-owned businesses in the region.

Is it legal for a public US university administration to advise its employees to patronize businesses owned by people of a specific race, both in their private lives and in the transaction of official university business?

Comment: An "anti-racism" initiative that is fundamentally racist?  This is an impressive application of newspeak, even for academia.

Comment: This sounds like advice. Is it required of the employees, even for work-related procurements?

Comment: It is not phrased as a requirement, but it seems clear this is something the administration is encouraging university employees to do.

Answer (score 4):

Advising employees to take some lawful action is legal, and is speech protected by the US Constitution. Campaigning for a political candidate could jeopardize the university's tax-exempt status, but there is no law requiring a university, even a government university, to remain politically neutral. That alone answers the question.

Whether or not the university could itself pursue racially-weighted business policies depends on what they are doing and what state it is in. It is generally legal to adopt policies that address discrimination, but 9 states have laws banning affirmative action. The cases [Grutter v. Bollinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grutter_v._Bollinger) and [Gratz v. Bollinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratz_v._Bollinger) establish that "blanket policies" run counter to the requirements of the 14th Amendment, but race can be used as a factor in making decisions. [Here is a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmative_action_in_the_United_States#Supreme_Court_Cases) or affirmative action related decisions in the US. As applied to a state's affirmative action programs, the standard of legality would be having a clear goal of limited scope without other workable race-neutral means to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks! The second paragraph of your answer seems like the key (so "that alone answers the question" was not quite correct...) - my state bans race-based discrimination in public education and contracting. From my reading of the relevant law, at least to my layman's understanding the behavior I was describing does not sound like it is complying with this ban.